# Put information from a dabtabse file into lists

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('newdb.db')
team_list = ['Munster', 'Leinster', 'Ulster', 'Glasgow']
cursor = db.cursor()
for i in range(len(team_list)):
    team_names = team_list[i].upper()

    searchStr = '%' + team_names + '%'
    cursor.execute('select * from tickets where Name LIKE ?', (searchStr,))

teams_points = cursor.fetchall()
print teams_points

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

This is my python code used to display all data in the table 'tickets' in newdb.db. I have a list with the team names and i want to be able to search these team names in the database and calculate information on tickets sold.
[picture of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXj4P.png)

```
[(u'MUNSTER', 5, u'First Round'), (u'MUNSTER', 5, u'First Round'), 
(u'MUNSTER', 8, u'Second Round'), (u'MUNSTER', 10, u'Both Rounds')]
[(u'LEINSTER', 2, u'Second Round'), (u'LEINSTER', 16, u'First Round'), 
(u'LEINSTER', 5, u'Both Rounds'), (u'LEINSTER', 6, u'Both Rounds'), 
(u'LEINSTER', 3, u'First Round')]
[(u'ULSTER', 10, u'Second Round')]
[(u'GLASGOW', 4, u'First Round')]
```

Above is my output when I run the script, **i want to be able put each team into a list as**

```
 team_list=['team_name', 'total first round tickets', 'second round tickets'] 


 munster_list = ['MUNSTER', '20', '18'] 
 leinster_list = ['LEINSTER','30','13'] 
 ulster_list = ['ULSTER','0','10'] 
 glasgow_list = ['GLASGOW','4','0']
```

so then to print the list I can just use print munster_list

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY to get one output row from the rows in each group. Use [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) to sum up only certain values:

```sql
SELECT Name,
       sum(CASE WHEN Type IN ('First Round', 'Both Rounds')
                THEN Amount
                ELSE 0
           END) AS "first round tickets",
       sum(CASE WHEN Type IN ('Second Round', 'Both Rounds')
                THEN Amount
                ELSE 0
           END) AS "second round tickets"
FROM tickets
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: i am realtively new to python and i am ensure where to put this

Comment: This is an SQL query. You give it to `execute()`.